# Moving file E93: More than one match

Tags: function, vim

The following function works (it opens and moves the desired file to a new or preexisting directory). But, I receive an error message concerning line 11 of the function `execute 'bwipeout '.expand(s:oldFileName)`. The error I receive is `E93: More than one match for <the old file name>`. I don't understand how this is possible because it has already successfully moved the file to the s:newFileName and the old file has been deleted. The new file's buffer doesn't have the same name as the old buffer. So, how would there be more than one match for the name of the old buffer?

```
command! -nargs=0 -bar MoveFile call s:functionMoveFile()
    function s:functionMoveFile() abort
        call dirvish#open("edit", 0)
        let s:oldFileName = expand("%:p")
        call inputsave()
        let s:newFileName = input("Move file here: ",expand(s:oldFileName),"file")
        call inputrestore()
        if s:newFileName != '' && s:newFileName != s:oldFileName
            execute 'sav '.fnameescape(s:newFileName)
            let s:newFileDirectory = expand("%:p:h")
            call delete(s:oldFileName)
            execute 'Dirvish '.expand(s:newFileDirectory)
            execute 'bwipeout '.expand(s:oldFileName)
        endif
    endfunction
```

I can prepend `silent!` to line 11 to avoid the error message. But, that isn't a proper fix. I don't know what else I should try because I am not asking vim to wipeout the new buffer and the old file's name doesn't match the new one. The command works as desired, but I would like to know what is incorrect about what I'm doing.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: FWIW, `:help delete()` deletes a file but it does nothing to its associated buffer.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, Sir. That is why I tried to use bwipeout for old buffer. But, then vim tells me there is more than one match for that buffer. This shouldn't be possible because the new buffer has a new name and the old buffer would be the only one with the old buffer name.